# How do I solve this dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am practising DP and I came across this question. http://www.spoj.com/problems/MPILOT/en/

Charlie acquired airline transport company and to stay in business he needs to lower the expenses by any means possible. There are N pilots working for his company (N is even) and N/2 plane crews needs to be made. A plane crew consists of two pilots - a captain and his assistant. A captain must be older than his assistant. Each pilot has a contract granting him two possible salaries - one as a captain and the other as an assistant. A captain's salary is larger than assistant's for the same pilot. However, it is possible that an assistant has larger salary than his captain. Write a program that will compute the minimal amount of money Charlie needs to give for the pilots' salaries if he decides to spend some time to make the optimal (i.e. the cheapest) arrangement of pilots in crews.

Input

The first line of input contains integer N, 2 ≤ N ≤ 10,000, N is even, the number of pilots working for the Charlie's company. The next N lines of input contain pilots' salaries. The lines are sorted by pilot's age, the salaries of the youngest pilot are given the first. Each of those N lines contains two integers separated by a space character, X i Y, 1 ≤ Y < X ≤ 100,000, a salary as a captain (X) and a salary as an assistant (Y).

Output

The first and only line of output should contain the minimal amount of money Charlie needs to give for the pilots' salaries.

After research, I found out this will be solved by DP but how exactly do I solve this? I have spent hours reading up on the links but I didn't get one which is easily understandable. Please help me.

Comment: Asking for spoj solutions is kinda cheating imho. But what do I know.

Comment: The thing is, I tried real real hard to solve it, and even came up with a recurrence but it didn't give the correct answer. I don't know what went wrong in that. If my logic was incorrect or something else, and finally I ended up posting it here. I don't do it either, but please help me for this one. It will be much appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a nice way to visualize it. Starting from the bottom left, the start of our ascending list, we can envision choosing a `Y` (assistant's salary) as a movement to the right and an `X` (captain's salary) as a movement up, with the condition that the southwest-northeast diagonal is not crossed (see [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) in Wikipedia).

[image: Cn is the number of monotonic lattice paths along the edges of a grid with n × n square cells, which do not pass above the diagonal. Image from Wikipedia.]

From this we can see that each node in the triangle has at most two predecessors, from the west or from the south, and so the bottom-up general case ought to be:

```
                    captain               assistant
dp[i][j] = min(x[i+j-1] + dp[i-1][j], y[i+j-1] + dp[i][j-1])

Example:

x = [4,5,6,7]
y = [3,2,1,2]

            [9+7]
     [3+5]  [min(8+1,5+6)]
[.]  [3]    [3+2]
```

I'll leave coding as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, we need to find a compact set of subproblems. Remembering the details of how the pilots are matched won't do -- we need something like the following characterization.

---

Consider a labeling that makes each pilot a captain or an assistant without regard to matching. There exists a valid matching if and only if the following two conditions hold:

1. There are N/2 captains and N/2 assistants.
2. For every age cutoff, there are at least as many assistants who are younger than the cutoff as there are captains who are younger than the cutoff.

The "only if" direction is easy: Condition 1 is obvious, and Condition 2 holds because the inequality holds for each 2-pilot crew, and we can sum the inequalities.

For the "if" direction, we actually have to construct crews. We proceed by induction. If there are no pilots, then the empty match is valid. Otherwise, since the youngest pilot is an assistant (by Condition 2) and there exists at least one captain (by Condition 1), there exists (by Sperner's lemma if you want to get fancy) a pair of pilots such that (a) no pilots are intermediate in age (b) the younger of the pair is an assistant (c) the older of the pair is a captain. Match the pair and remove them from the pool. Observe that both Conditions still hold, so match the rest by inductive hypothesis.

---

This observation leads to an O(N^2)-time dynamic program. We repeatedly read the salaries of the next oldest pilot and then compute, given that K pilots have been considered so far, for all C from 0 to [K/2], the minimum cost of paying K - C assistants and C captains among these pilots. At the end, return the cost of paying N/2 assistants and N/2 captains. Untested Python:

```
def cost(pilots):
    cost = [0]
    for i, (assistant_salary, captain_salary) in enumerate(pilots):
        cost.append(float('inf'))  # two-way sentinel
        cost = [min(cost[c] + assistant_salary,
                    cost[c - 1] + captain_salary)
                for c in range((i + 1) / 2 + 1)]
    return cost[-1]  # i.e., N/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's formulate some conditions for a recursion: if we've reached the end, return the sum; if we have `N/2` assistants, add a captain next; if we have the same number of assistants as captains left, add an assistant next (we can't have a captain younger than an assistant); otherwise, return the minimum cost of either adding a captain or an assistant.

JavaScript code:

```js
var x = [4,5,6,7];
var y = [3,2,1,2];
var n = x.length;

function f(i,ys,s){
  if (i == n){
    return s;
  }
  if (ys == n / 2){
    return f(i + 1,ys,s + x[i]);
  } else if (i % 2 == 0 && ys == i / 2){
    return f(i + 1,ys + 1,s + y[i]);
  } else {
    return Math.min(f(i + 1,ys + 1,s + y[i]),f(i + 1,ys,s + x[i]));
  }
}
```

Output:

```js
console.log(f(0,0,0)) // 16
```

Answer (score 0):

For recursive approach in c++, you can follow this code for better understanding:

```
int min_salary(int a[],int n,int x,int c[])
{
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    if(x==0)
        return(a[0]+min_salary(a+1,n-1,1,c+1));
    if(x==n)
        return(c[0]+min_salary(a+1,n-1,x-1,c+1));
    else
        return(min(a[0]+min_salary(a+1,n-1,x+1,c+1),c[0]+min_salary(a+1,n-1,x-1,c+1)));
}
```